# Using const bool reference for background task cancellation tracking? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a desktop application where certain computations, when requested by the user, are run in a background thread.  There is a cancel button.

I know the "safe" or "correct" ways of signaling cancellation to the background task (using Qt signal/slot connections, mutex-wrapped booleans on which the background task polls, etc.).

However, the simplest thing seems to me to be having a `bool cancelled` in my main-thread class, which is set synchronously when the Cancel button is pressed, and passing a `const bool &cancelled` to the background thread, on which it polls.

Is there any realistic way this approach can backfire?

Comment: Non synchronized shared state can backfire due to unintended interactions in the hardware. If the bool is aligned this is essentially an atomic bool on ARM/X86

Comment: Can you give me an example of an interaction in the hardware that could lead to a bad outcome for me if I take no particular precautions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The threads may run on separate processors, each with its own cache. If the boolean is atomic you can do this. Otherwise you risk that a change is only propagated as far as the nearest cache, and not visible to the other thread.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this point now.  Does the presence of a mutex guarding the variable solve this issue?  If so, can you explain how?

Comment: @Andrey, yes it does, see my comment on Sneftel's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you respect the niceties of inter-thread data access (in MSVC, flag variable should be volatile*; either set it atomically, or execute a write barrier afterwards), this is fine. It's a pretty common approach.

*`volatile` is not normally the right way to do this, but MSVC's semantics make it an effective way to ensure the visibility of the write.

Comment: I don't really understand.  Is it really necessary to set guards around reads/writes to this boolean?  My understanding is that due to the aliasing problem, it isn't as though the compiler can optimize out reads to it or something like that.

Comment: I guess my real question is, what exactly could go wrong?

Comment: @Andrey That's volatile. Atomics is something different.

Comment: @Andrey If the flag is not an atomic and there's no write barrier, the compiler and/or the CPU could decide to indefinitely defer actually writing the flag in a manner visible to the other thread.

Comment: So the right solution is actually to guard reads/writes to the flag with a mutex?

I guess as a side question, I don't understand how the presence of the mutex actually helps the compiler (or CPU?) to understand that it needs to update the state of the cache lines referring to the variable.

Comment: @Andrey You don't need a mutex, just an atomic. The reason the mutex works is that it induces global read/write barriers, just as atomics induce local read/write barriers.

Comment: @Andrey functions to lock/unlock mutexes will include (or at least cause execution of) appropriate processor instructions to ensure processor-level caches are flushed so that memory (i.e. variables) written before the unlock is visible to other processors in the system.